# How does pool mining work in Ethereum?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, miner

When mining in pools, does a user get the mining reward for a block as a function of computational resources even if he did not find the PoW for that block?

My guess is that the rewarding scheme is pool specific.

Answer (score 1):

Every pool has different policies.  They publish their policies on their respective web sites.

In general miners get paid based on the percentage of the total compute cycles they supplied, but this is not always the case.